# css: stop words from flowing to another line without a non-breaking space?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make links where the text does not flow to the next line without putting in non-breaking spaces in between the words?

I need to be able to set the width: auto on the link also.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">keep all words on the same line</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont quite understand. What should be the result? Can you put up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the following:

```
a { white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: depending on the circumstance, display: inline-block may help too.